# Android. List all running activities in android above 5

Tags: java, android

Please help me.
How i can get list of all running activities in Android above 5?
I tryed a few samples, but did not get right result..

Comment: send me your code

Comment: you can't get list of running activities on Android 5+

Comment: It would be more helpful if you post your code.